# How to change a review evaluation?

Tags: support, review-queues

I accidentally rejected an edit for a reason that was blatantly wrong and I'd like to revoke it.

[image: dumb rejection]

It mistakenly looked to me like the edit removed all the tags, I misunderstood the comparison view since I haven't done reviews in a while. Is there a way to change my evaluation from reject to accept?

Comment: I'm also considering a feature request to display the tags on both sides of the comparison view. Does anyone else think that is worthwhile?

Comment: You mean kind of like the markdown view but different?

Comment: @Comintern the markdown view does not display the tags on both sides either. I think it would just make the comparison more obvious. Omitting the tags from the right side when none of them are changed makes it look like all the tags were removed by the edit, at least to me.

Comment: Ahhh... those tags.  :facepalm:.  Is it Friday yet?

Comment: You missed where they removed the entire title too `;)` (That's another thing that I'd like to see on both sides.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users clicking the [wrong button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/158100) happens all the time. That is why most review actions need three or more people to agree on an outcome. And even after the fact it is still possible to rectify anything that passed through the cracks.

On suggested edits I wouldn't even bother if you clicked reject when accept was intended, given the fair amount of robo-reviewers in that queue that accept anything you throw at them.

The only case were I would be concerned if you accepted blatant spam or vandalism. In those cases take the blame and hop in a chatroom to seek for help getting the right thing done. One of those rooms is [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and the regulars there are ready to offer advice, assist you in moderation tasks or fight bad edits.